# Importing text object programmatically in navision 2009

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2009

I have a Research task of importing object in text file into Dynamics Navision 2009 using C#. I am not getting a single clue to do this. Please help me to find whether we can do it in Nav 2009 or not. If yes then How?

In Nav 2013 we can import text object using finsql.exe command in command prompt. Is there anything similar for Nav 2009?

**Update**
Now, the requirement has been change. I want to have check in/check out functionality for nav objects. Is there any tool to support check in/check out.

Comment: You need create a **C#** process to import object in txt format? or you only need import object in txt format in NAV 2009?

Comment: You can't. It was not possible in Nav 2009

Comment: Mak Sim has right - you can't do this with finsql.exe. I you desperate you can find 3rd party solutions

Answer (score 1):

Thad Ryker's C/SIDE integration utilities use the same technology as the old Navision Developer's Toolkit (NDT) used to use for communicating with the NAV client - you might want to take a look at that.

http://mibuso.com/downloads/c-side-integration-utilities-v1.4

Answer (score 1):

In NAV 2009 R2, there is a C/AL function IMPORTOBJECTS that allows you to import text objects. Unfortunately, it doesn't work neither via RTC or web services, nor on NAS.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996623.aspx

But you might think of a way to implement a codeunit that will import necessary files listed in some table (filled externally), and then run this codeunit by starting NAV with special parameters, e.g.:

http://forum.mibuso.com/discussion/33306/run-codeunit-from-outside-nav
http://techblog.byllemos.com/2008/03/starting-navision-from-another-application/